# SignalR Client Methods not firing consistently

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a simple SignalR proxy with a single client method on it. The javascript looks like the following:

```
var proxy = $.connection.orderStatusUpdateEmitter;
proxy.client.onOrderUpdated = function(order){
  try {
    //This is only hit sometimes
    getCustomerOrders(userId)
  } catch (e) {

  }
}

proxy.connection.start().done(function(c){
  $log.info('Connected to order status update emitter');
});

proxy.connection.disconnected = function(data){
  $log.info('disconnected');
  setTimeout(function() {
      proxy.connection.start();
   },20000);
}
```

It seems like there is some type of race condition or I am doing this incorrectly because the handler for `onOrderUpdated` is not consistently hit. Anything glaringly wrong with the implementation above?

There is nothing special happening in my hub on the server, it looks like the following:

```
[AuthorizeClaims]
public class OrderStatusUpdateEmitter : Hub
{
    private static string _groupIdentifier = "OrderStatusUpdate";


    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var identity = Context.Request.Environment["user.identity"] as AuthenticatedUserIdentity;
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, string.Format("{0}-{1}", _groupIdentifier, identity.UserId));
        return base.OnConnected();
    }


    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        var identity = Context.Request.Environment["user.identity"] as AuthenticatedUserIdentity;
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, string.Format("{0}-{1}", _groupIdentifier, identity.UserId));
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    public static string GetGroupIdentifier()
    {
        return _groupIdentifier;
    }

    public Order OnOrderUpdate(Order order)
    {
        Clients.Group(String.Format("{0}-{1}",GetGroupIdentifier(),
                                                order.CustomerId)).onOrderUpdated(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your hub code..

Comment: @Madhu updated with the hub code

Comment: "the handler for onOrderUpdated is not consistently hit" I assume it is a group issue. Try the same with `Clients.All` instead of `Clients.Group` ... in the `OnOrderUpdate` to see it. Debug to what groups the event is going.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of Group
  list is consisting of users with ',' separator.

```
string[] group = list.Split(',');

  for(int i=0; i < group.length; i++)

  Clients.User(group[i]).onOrderUpdated(obj);
```